# How to enable code shift panel in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019

According to this post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74157/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-visual-studio I decided to post my question here.

In Visual Studio Code at the right side there is long area with minimized code view with brighter place whereby can I shift code from top to bottom. Is there a way to enable this feature in normal Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the **Map** mode in Scroll Bars options:

[image]

[image]